# Get formcontrol name of element in an FormArray

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

I am using FormArray in side a form. I am able to get fines which is of type FormArray  by using code below but I am not able to get controls inside FormArray element. Is there any way to get controls inside FormArray element?

```js
createForm(): void {
    this.transactionForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      date: [this.today],
      fines: this.formBuilder.array([]),
  
    });
}
  
  
  
get fines(): FormArray {
    return this.transactionForm.get('fines') as FormArray;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried at method(presuming you know the index of element in the array)
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by using **index** followed by **get()** with the **name** of the control which you would like to get :

```
    const lines = this.transactionForm.get('lines') as FormArray;
      
    // suppose you have a control with name notes then  
    console.log('notes', lines.controls[0].get('notes'));
```

Answer (score 0):

this.transactionForm.controls[index].get('propertyName').value